# vercel 504 timeout how can I solve it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I generate pdfs and it may take 2 seconds or when I have a lot of data to generate then it takes 200 seconds. So I used a queue not to block the response but I also get the serverless function crashed and it does not continue after 10 seconds. I can upgrade the plan but the max seconds is then 60. I need more, so is there another solution to buy the enterprise plan?

Comment: Vercel's enterprise plan increases the limit to 900 seconds, so that'd be the way to go. Other than that, it's not possible on Vercel, so you'll need to use another service in combination with Vercel. Maybe wizz up a VPN with DigitalOcean (or similar) and have the PDF generation script there, where you won't be limited by execution time.